# Why AutomaticDecompression of HttpClientHandler is by default None

Tags: c#, compression

I was confused that by default HttpClient/HttpClientHandler is not using compression. In order to turn it on there is need to use `AutomaticDecompression` specifying the algorithm of compression method.
The MS [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.automaticdecompression?view=net-5.0) states following:

> For the .NET Framework 4.x System.Net.Http binary in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC), the default value is None.
> When the System.Net.Http NuGet package v4.1.0 to v4.3.2 is used, the default is GZip and Deflate.
> After NuGet package v4.3.2, the default value of None is used.

Compression can drastically improve response time. I am wondering if by default we should always submit `DecompressionMethods.All`? Are there any possible downsides?

Comment: FWIW most if not all the time, you'll deal with either `GZip` and or `Deflate`. It's best to only include the ones you would need for example: `myWebRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;` Since `DecompressionMethods` is an enum, the default set is `None`; the first in the enum. On another note, if targeting .NET 5 you'll have other options as far a decompression, anything < .Net 4.8 your options shrink.

Comment: I assume they changed the default and then back because yeah often compression is better then no compression but changing default is a bad thing by itself. A changed default that changes behaviour unexpectedly isn't what you want as developer. So they thought changing the default to a better value might be a good thing but people hit by a changed default made them think otherwise.

Comment: `Are there any possible downsides?` Well compression, but its very nature, will consume CPU cycles.